# Working with strings in C++11 how to satisfy conditions?

Tags: c++, string, char

Given a string, I want to check if it satisfies the following conditions:

1. it consists only of small letter, big letters, numbers, `[` or `]` or `;`
2. If `[]` appear they must be correctly placed, in other words after each `[` there is `]` and before each `]` there is `[`

For example, this is legal: `[x1[x3]]`
While this isn't: `[x1]]x2[`

3. if `;` appears it must appear between `[]`

For example, this is legal: `[;;;]` , `[a;bb]`
While this isn't: `x1[];y "`

**I have finished 1 but stuck on 2 and 3, any help?**

Comment: How is this legal `[[x3[x1`? It violates _"after each `[` there is `]`"_

Comment: Read about `Regex`

Comment: @churill and Thomas thanks for letting me know! I don't know why but for some reason all the examples got rotated (Fixed now)

Comment: @FarbodAhmadian regex isn't a good solution when you need to match opens with closes.

Comment: @MarkRansom Hmm... I didn't know about that. Would you mind please give me reasons with an example? (Cause I taught problems with `openings and closings` can also have a pattern that we can extract them using `capture groups`)

Comment: @FarbodAhmadian: Now you aren't talking about regular expressions, but about the extensions supported by some particular regular expressions library (and they are by no means standardized or portable)

Answer (score 5):

Just walk the string one character at a time from left to right (ranged-for is good for this), and keep track of the nesting level (number of unmatched `[`).

Rule 1: obvious test on the character

Rule 2: if `[` increment the nesting level, if `]` decrement the nesting level.  If the level becomes negative that's an error.  If it isn't back to zero at the end of the string that's an error.

Rule 3: if `;` then the nesting level must be at least 1, if it is (less than or) equal to zero that is an error.

Answer (score 1):

For keeping the track of `[` and `]`, you can keep a track of all the `[` encountered until now that doesn't have a matching `]`  for them. You can also check if `;` lies in the same logic.

```
int countBrackets = 0;

for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
{
   if(str[i] == '[')
   {
      countBrackets++;
   }
   else if(str[i] == ']')
   {
      if(countBrackets == 0) return false;
      else countBrackets--;
   }
   else if(str[i] == ';')
   {
      if(countBrackets == 0) return false;
   }
}

if(countBrackets > 0) return false;
```

Comment: Well done @Jasmeet initially I thinked using a stack or queue but this is simple and clear idea

Answer (score 1):

Well this idea is like @Jasmeet but with all conditions just like @BenVoidt says:

```
bool check(string x){
    int bracketSence=0;
    for(int i=0; i < x.size(); ++i){
        //First Condition
        if(islower(x[i]) || isupper(x[i]) || (x[i] >= '0' && x[i]<= '9') ||
           x[i] == '[' || x[i] == ']' || x[i] == ';'){
               //Second and Third Condition
               if(x[i] == '[')      ++bracketSence;
               else if(x[i] == ']') --bracketSence;
               else if(x[i] == ';' && bracketSence<1) return false;
               if(bracketSence < 0) return false;
           }
        else return false;
    }
    return bracketSence == 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, How may I reach you? Have FB or Insta (Not for the purpose of this code)

Comment: In the [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) or give me your username in some social network @DanielRob